# How to calculate critical values for Dunnett procedure given alpha, df1 and df2

Tags: r, anova, multiple-comparisons, quantiles

I am looking for an R function that can calculate critical values for a Dunnett multiple comparison procedure for any family-wise error rate and degrees of freedoms.

In short, I need similar functions to the two below found in R to calculate quantiles for the fisher and studentized distribution:

```
f_crit <- qf(p, df1, df2, lower.tail=F)
q_crit <- qtukey(p, df1, df2, lower.tail=F)
```

Is there any R package that provide similar function for the critical values of Dunnett?

`d_crit <- ???(p, df1, df2)`

Comment: Python modules will do too, or any standalone implementation in C or fortran.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out the `nCDunnett` package contain functions to calculate the quantiles similar to `qf()` and `qtukey()` above.

For one-tailed distribution:

```
>require(nCDunnett)
>df1 = 5
>df2 = 7
>p = 0.01
>q = qNCDun(p=1-p, nu=df2, rho=(rep(0.5,times=df1)), delta=rep(0,times=df1), two.sided=F)
```

`>q`

3.958376

Giving similar output as the table values found in text-books, such as [dunnett-1side.pdf](http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~winner/tables/dunnett_1side.pdf). The `qNCDun()` function, however, operates an order of magnitude slower than `qf()` and `qtukey()`.

Comment: Great to have R code...but only if it works. [Here](http://pascencio.cos.ucf.edu/classes/Methods/Dunnett's%20table.pdf) is the link to Dunnett's paper (including tables). As you can see on p. 488, the values in column 3 rows 24 and 30 are 2.51 and 2.47, respectively. These would be the values for 3 comparison groups (and one control) and MS_error degrees of freedom of 24 & 30.

Comment: Unfortunately, the following R code to obtain the same values `library(nCDunnett); `   
`qNCDun(0.95, 24, rep.int(0.5,3), rep.int(0,3), 16, two.sided=TRUE) # should be 2.51 (from table); `   
  `qNCDun(0.95, 30, rep.int(0.5,3), rep.int(0,3), 16, two.sided=TRUE) # should be 2.47 `  
  produces different values: 2.478931 & 2.445402, neither of which round to the values reported in the original paper (or in any of the other tables I've located).

Comment: @Gregg It actually works if you replace 16 with higher number (for example with default 32). While slowing calculation down it increases precision. `nCDunnett::qNCDun(0.95, 24, rep.int(0.5,3), rep.int(0,3), 32, two.sided=TRUE) `  results in 2.5068 which can be rounded to 2.51. Same with second example which give us  2.4738 $\approx$ 2.47.

Comment: This package is no longer available via CRAN.

Answer (score 1):

```
qDunnett <- function (p, df, k, rho,
                      type = c("two-sided", "one-sided"))
{
  type <- match.arg(type)
  alpha <- 1 - p
  if (type == "two-sided") {
    alpha <- alpha/2
  }
  S <- matrix(rho, nrow=k, ncol=k) + (1-rho)*diag(k)
  if (type == "two-sided") {
    f <- function(d, df, k, S, p) {
      mnormt::sadmvt(df=df, lower=rep(-d,k), upper=rep(d,k),
                      mean=rep(0,k), S=S, maxpts=2000*k) - p
    }
  }
  else {
    f <- function(d, df, k, S, p) {
      mnormt::pmt(d, S=S, df=df) - p
    }
  }
  d <- uniroot(f,
               df = df, k = k, S = S, p=p,
               lower=qt(1 - alpha, df),
               upper=qt(1 - alpha/k, df),
               tol=.Machine$double.eps, maxiter=5000)$root
  return(d)
}
```

Test:

```
> p <- 0.95; df <- 24; rho <- 0.5; k <- 3
> nCDunnett::qNCDun(p=p, nu=df, rho=rho,
+                   delta=rep(0,times=k), two.sided=T)
[1] 2.506845
> qDunnett(p, df, k, rho)
[1] 2.506654
```